# ASP.NET MVC 2 not displaying images in CSS files

Tags: c#, css, iis, image, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a small app I've written, and it works well when using the dev server, but as soon as i switch to IIS on my local box (IIS 7), I lose images and styles.

I tried using Url.Content and that kind of works for styles and images in the master page, but I still lose images that are referenced from CSS styles

Is there any way I can get this to work in both the local mode and via localhost/iis?

I suspect this has something to do with virtual directories, but don't know IIS well enough to say for sure.

Thanks.

Comment: are you images in your css file using relative paths?

Comment: Yes they use relative pathing. I also checked to make sure the images were published (they were). I really do not want to resort to hardwiring the image paths in the css files. It locks the app to a specific virtual dir if I do that.

Comment: check the path of image files in firebug and then try opening them in browser by copying and pasting this in address bar with base url . you will definitely not be able to see them. Check with various combination in url . I guess you are using wrong relative path

Comment: Firebug reports:  http://localhost/MyApp/Content/css/style.css  (not found). Interestingly, when i tried that directly, the route engine took over. I thought iis served .css files statically.
http://localhost/MyApp/Content/images/header.gif comes up fine, but
http://localhost/MyApp/Content/css/style.css comes back asking for a login (I've secured the app). Going to try some more things..

Comment: do you still have the problem? you've accepted the answer suggesting you publish the images, but you say you've done that.

Is there now a different problem?

From what I can gather MVC is trying to serve the CSS file to your browser, if that's the case then I would take a look at your IIS config to make sure you've not configured ASP.NET to process CSS files. Failing that it sound like your might need to tweak your routing in the MVC code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you publish or upload your images? If you did not add your images into your project, they will not be published.

More questions:

Have you updated any routing rules? If so, please show them to us. Do you declare any authorisation attributes over your controllers?

Comment: @Sunil, can you tell us where is your stylesheet and your images? Please upload to here a portion of your css.

Comment: images are in:  Content/images/*.gif  styles are in: Content/css/style.css
Here is a sample style:
div#header
{
    background-image: url(../../Content/images/header.gif);
    position:relative;
    height:47px;
    margin:0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

Comment: I added some more questions. But following up on this, are any of the styles referred in this style sheet appear in the generated output html page?

Comment: I moved style.css to the same level as Site.css. I then checked that I could see Site.css using the browser.. I can.  Then I checked style.css, lo and behold, it told me it could not find the file... wierd, both files are there. I'm starting to wonder if I am not fighting a vista permissions problem

Comment: Hah!! not permissions, the css file was encrypted. which means iis7 cannot dish up encrypted files. Now the css is being seen and the layout is correct. Just the images left..   getting closer :)

Comment: Bingo! its working.  Word of advice to the unsuspecting. Vista might encrypt files on you, and if those files are part of your web app, you'll run into headaches like i did. Everything is working now. Thanks for the help.. it helped me narrow this down.